# Создание треугольника с заданными сторонами

Tags: javascript, css, графика

Есть четыре формы, которые служат для того, чтобы пользователь ввёл значения трёх сторон треугольника и одного угла между ними, и на основе этих данных появилась фигура. Была попытка реализации этого с помощью CSS-свойств border-left, border-bottom и прочих, но проблема заключалась в том, что нельзя было контролировать длину одной из трёх сторон, и нельзя было применить "обводку" к фигуре вместо закрашивания.

```js
function draw() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("section")[0].innerHTML = "";
  var sideA = document.forms[0].elements.sideA.value;
  var sideB = document.forms[0].elements.sideB.value;
  var sideC = document.forms[0].elements.sideC.value;
  var angle = document.forms[0].elements.angle.value;
  var triangle = document.createElement("div");
  triangle.style.borderLeft = 90 - angle + "px solid transparent";
  triangle.style.borderRight = sideC + "px solid transparent";
  triangle.style.borderBottom = sideA + "px solid red";
  triangle.style.width = "0";
  document.getElementsByTagName("section")[0].appendChild(triangle);
}
```

```css
section {
  width: 47vmin;
  height: 47vmin;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
<form>
  Side A:
  <input type="number" name="sideA" oninput="draw()">
  Side B:
  <input type="number" name="sideB" oninput="draw()">
  Side C:
  <input type="number" name="sideC" oninput="draw()">
  Angle:
  <input type="number" name="angle" oninput="draw()">
</form>
```

Comment: может лучше свг/канвас?

Comment: @ThisMan Хорошо, а как реализовать создание треугольника с определенными длинами сторон через polygon SVG?